# PDO fetch() no errors but no results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm not getting any error message, but I'm also not getting any results from this query. I am just trying to get the password hash that is associated with the email provided. What am I doing wrong?

```
$selectEmailStmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT passHash FROM userbasicinfo WHERE email=?");
$selectEmailStmt->bindParam(1, $email);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$selectEmailStmt->execute();
$selectEmailStmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $selectEmailStmt->fetch();


echo $result;
```

Comment: You need to have/declare `$email = $_POST['email'];` on top

Comment: No... no you do not @Fred-ii- The parameters are passed by reference.

Comment: @Neal oh, how so? You'd think that `$email` hasn't been declared, due to `$selectEmailStmt->bindParam(1, $email);` and `$email = $_POST['email'];` below it.

Comment: The code is perfectly fine.

Comment: @steele -- Did you try this query directly in MySQL to make sure that it had results?

Comment: Try echoing out your `$_POST['email']` variable, to check it actually contains something.

Comment: How about wrapping it in a try...catch to check for errors?

Comment: Why do you expect an error? A query that returns no results is not an error, it just means that nothing matched the `WHERE` criteria in the DB.

Comment: @j08691 to let you know, wrapping WON'T make check for errors

Comment: @Neal Since when are strings passed by reference? :)

Comment: @Leri The binds are passed by reference, creating a temporary placeholder. The variable only needs declaring before the `execute()`. `Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.` http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @BenFortune Oops, misunderstood context.

Comment: @Neal I ran the query directly in MySQL and it did have results. But @ Your Common Sense's answer works perfectly so I'm not going to bother with fiddling with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no errors

Errors won't appear just by itself. You have to configure your environment to report them.
Here your code with useless statements taken out and error reporting added instead.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$sql = "SELECT passHash FROM userbasicinfo WHERE email=?";
$pass = $DBH->prepare($sql)->execute([$_POST['email']])->fetchColumn();
var_dump($pass, $_POST['email']);
```

if still no result - then no such email in the table.

Comment: I used this code and it returned the hash with no problems. I still don't understand exactly why mine wasn't working though.